# My SQL query showing error : : #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I have a problem regarding mysql.

I have few tables like tbl_follow, tbl_user, tbl_post_like,

Now what I want is that my query should return the result like:

i want userid, username, user image, user state from one table->tbl_user,
then i want those users who are following other friend(other user) only if the column "estatus" in table "tbl_follow" contain value as "Active" otherwise if there is an "inactive" value then it should return 0 as i have coded in query.

tbl_follow : 1.iFollowID, 2.iUserID, 3. iFriendID, 4. eStatus

tbl_post_like: 1. iPostLikeID, 2. iUserID, 3. iPostID

tbl_user: 1.iUserID, 2. vUsername, 3. vImage, 4. vState

Now the simple query I am using is:

```
SELECT u.iUserID,
       u.vUsername,
       u.vState,
       u.vImage,

  (SELECT IF(
               (SELECT iFollowID
                FROM tbl_follow
                WHERE iUserID =249
                  AND iFriendID = 250
                  AND eStatus = 'Active')!='', 1,0)
   FROM tbl_follow) AS is_follow
FROM tbl_user u
INNER JOIN tbl_post_like l ON u.iUserID=l.iUserID
WHERE l.iPostID=21
```

Comment: What is the problem?  You say "i want those users who are following other friend" but the error is because you are returning multiple rows.  It sounds like you need to get your main user (singular) in one query and get the users (plural) that are following in another query

Comment: This isn't a mysql problem, and I can't see why it's tagged with phpmyadmin whatsoever. Also the error message is pretty clear. Seems like you need to study SQL and MySQL in particular more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about performance on this in comparison to using an additional join, but hopefully it'll work:

Try:

```
SELECT u.iUserID,
       u.vUsername,
       u.vState,
       u.vImage,
       IF(EXISTS
               (SELECT iFollowID
                FROM tbl_follow
                WHERE iUserID =249
                  AND iFriendID = 250
                  AND eStatus = 'Active'), 1,0) AS is_follow
FROM tbl_user u
INNER JOIN tbl_post_like l ON u.iUserID=l.iUserID
WHERE l.iPostID=21
```

Comment: SELECT *, IF((SELECT iFollowID FROM tbl_follow WHERE iUserID = 271 AND iFriendID = 250 AND eStatus = 'Active')!='', 1,0) as is_follow FROM `tbl_user` WHERE iUserID = 271

Comment: Actually, looking at the query again, I think I know what may be the problem, you don't have to nest it so many times... I'll edit the query and see if that works?